# My apartment's mains voltage rises from 220 V at noon to 245 V at night

Tags: voltage, mains

I'm Egyptian, and the standard mains voltage in Egypt is between 220 V to 240 V.

The mains voltage in my apartment keeps rising daily from **220 V at noon** to **245 V at night**.

Should I worry, and what should I do?

Comment: lack of normal load usage due to pandemic.  Poor load and supply regulation.  Unplug non-essential items of importance. Worry about some SMPS if it goes above 250V. Use a power bar with suitable MOV transient protection and breaker.

Comment: No, you should not worry. +/- 10% deviation from the center (231V) is within the expectable range.

Comment: Turn the biggest load in your house on and off. Do you see more than a couple volts of movement when you do?  There is a problem called a "Lost Neutral" that can happen to households that receive more than one phase, or whole neighborhoods if there's a problem at the transformer.

Comment: iirc the spec in the UK is +10% and -6% from a centre of 230V . Had issues with a wind turbine not able to push into grid as grid was too high...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe electricity with your poor voltage regulation costs less than with normal and good voltage regulation.
Maybe your electricity uses old transformers that were designed for less power that is used today and should be replaced with more powerful (and more expensive and larger) transformers.
The transformers and underground wiring on my street in Canada worked fine but were replaced when they reached 30 years old. The voltage regulation and reliability are excellent.

Comment: But should s/he worry and what should s/he do? That was the question.